# terraform multiple providers not working with s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Im trying to do this:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "resources"
    region = "us-east-1"
    key = "resources"
  }
}

// the default region
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

//for creating buckets in other regions- region param broken stupid issue with aws_s3_bucket resource...
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "east1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "zzzzz" {
  provider = "aws.east1"
  bucket = "zzzzz"
  acl    = "private"
  force_destroy = true
}
```

And getting error

```
 Error creating S3 bucket: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-2'
```

Comment: seems i might just be running into this issue: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/227569527-Can-not-create-S3-Bucket-after-change-AWS-region

Comment: Can you share the debug log as well? Specifically looking for the `[DEBUG] S3 bucket create: ` lines from it. If you run `export TF_LOG_PATH=tf.log` and `export TF_LOG=DEBUG` and then `grep "[DEBUG] S3 bucket create: " tf.log after an `apply` that should give you the relevant parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to wait 1hour + because I recreated bucket in different region

Answer (score 3):

This may also happen if your bucket name is not globally unique (not within your account only). Trying a different (usually longer) name would help

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to your S3 bucket name. Following my example, I had this name: `my_bucket`

When I changed to a more detailed name (`my-project-s3-state-bucket`) the error disappeared.

So, in conclusion, your s3 bucket should be globally unique.
PS: Yeah, I agree that the terraform/aws provider error isn't friendly to understand.